# Missing _X_AMZN_TRACE_ID variable in os.environ

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I've been using the _X_AMZN_TRACE_ID variable but today realized it was missing in one of my lambda functions. Is it phased out now?
Any help reaccesing it?

Edit:
I read this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-concepts.html#xray-concepts-traces, which suggests there still should be this variable though which is strange.

Comment: it seems to me that the value would be present in the request header or passed context, not in an environment variable, unless about the way AWS thinks about the traces that misaligns with my experience.

Comment: how do I access the request headers?

Comment: to add more context, i'm using the serverless framework to do xray logging.

Comment: I suggest printing out the context and event objects that are passed to the lambda handler. If the trace id is present you should see it in one of those payloads. Otherwise, there’s something else going on here in terms of your setup.

Comment: I am using nodejs runtime and I can access it without a problem.
The docs suggest it should be there too:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime

Have you tried migrating to python 3?

Comment: I just used a different variable.